# ElasticSearch: If split-brain occurs, can a replica node be rejected by cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've faced a situation recently like this:

My cluster has 3 nodes. 1 is not a data node and can never be a master. The other 2 can. The minimum master nodes is set to 2 for all of these nodes.

The 2 data nodes store the exact same index with all shards. 1 is just a replica of the other.

1 of the nodes crashed and had to restart, but afterwards it could never rejoin the cluster even though I see it is trying to.

Here is what I see in the logs:

```
[2014-03-12 08:07:31,571][INFO ][discovery.zen] [Search 6] failed to send join 
request to master [[Search 6][Zsg_fKviRW6eJJG3aYIWeA][BLAHBLAH]
[inet[/BLAHBLAH:9300]]],
reason [org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [Search 6]
[inet[/BLAHBLAH:9300]][discovery/zen/join];
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalStateException:
Node [[Search 6][vwurISIMTTC-Ra1EmiI8vA][BLAHBLAH][inet[/BLAHBLAH:9300]]]
not master for join request from [[Search 6][vwurISIMTTC-Ra1EmiI8vA]
[BLAHBLAH [inet[/BLAHBLAH:9300]]]]
```

(Note IPs were overwritten with BLAHBLAH above).

What does this mean?

Comment: is the cluster name correct in all nodes config/elasticsearch.yml? What kind of discovery do you have configured? If you are using explicit zen ping do you have the correct hosts in all the config files?

Comment: Can you please add to the question which version of Elasticsearch you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`not master for join request`

This error means that the nodeId of the master in the clusterJoinRequest does not match the actual nodeId of the master node receiving the request.

You can see in the logs that the localNode elected a master with the **Zsg_fKviRW6eJJG3aYIWeA** id:

> [Search 6] failed to send join  request to master [[Search
>   6][**Zsg_fKviRW6eJJG3aYIWeA**][BLAHBLAH] [inet[/BLAHBLAH:9300]]]

But the actual nodeId at the address that received the join request was **vwurISIMTTC-Ra1EmiI8vA**:

> Node [[Search
>   6][**vwurISIMTTC-Ra1EmiI8vA**][BLAHBLAH][inet[/BLAHBLAH:9300]]] not master
>   for join request

The weird thing is that the logs show that the node sending the request is the same as the node receiving the request.  How are you getting the address for the nodes?  Also, do all the nodes have the same name?  If not, you might just want to restart to reset the nodeId.

> Node [[Search
>   6][**vwurISIMTTC-Ra1EmiI8vA**][BLAHBLAH][inet[/BLAHBLAH:9300]]] not master
>   for join request from [[Search 6][**vwurISIMTTC-Ra1EmiI8vA**] [BLAHBLAH
>   [inet[/BLAHBLAH:9300]]]]